# CMFCPropertSheet with wizard mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I'm trying to give some modernized look to a old MFC application. I have changed all the CPropertSheet and CPropertPages to CMFCPropertSheets and CMFCPropertPage. 
I was success when using `SetLook(CMFCPropertySheet::PropSheetLook_List);` in normal mode.

Can I use CMFCPropertSHeet and CMFCPropertPages to get wizard mood looks as follows
[image]

Comment: What is your problem setting the style you want and use SetWizardMode?

Comment: Forget my question. It doesn't work. The internal style handling doesn't support this.

Comment: @xMRi Thanks. Are there any other way that I can achieve this?

Comment: The only way I see is to place your own CListCtrl on the left side and fill it with the information you want. Maybe CHtmlCtrl may work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

use the [CMFCPropertySheet::SetLook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb983414(v=vs.100).aspx) method with CMFCPropertySheet::PropSheetLook_List or whatever you want it to be,

since CMFCPropertySheet derives from [CPropertySheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/d3fkt014(v=vs.100).aspx) you can follow these instructions to do what you wanna achieve:
MSDN link: [CPropertySheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/d3fkt014(v=vs.100).aspx)

> *To create a wizard-type dialog box, follow the same steps that you would follow to create a standard property sheet, but call SetWizardMode before you call DoModal. To enable the wizard buttons, call SetWizardButtons, using flags to customize their function and appearance. To enable the Finish button, call SetFinishText after the user has taken action on the last page of the wizard.*